# Rails routing when nesting resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, rails-routing, activeresource

I'm trying to figure out how to specify the route I'm trying to use but I keep getting routing errors. Can someone please point out where I'm going wrong and maybe explain what a better way to do this might be?

I'm working with these (nested) resources:

```
resources :users do
  resources :playlists
end
```

Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :playlists
end

class Playlist < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

Now I'm trying to link to a user's playlists inside the user/show.html.erb file:

```
<p>
  <%= link_to "Playlists", user_playlists_path(@playlist)%></p>
</p>
```

Which brings me to a Playlists page (/users/1/playlists) successfully but when I try adding a new playlist for this user, I get the following error:

```
Showing /app/views/playlists/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `playlists_path' for #<#<Class:0x0000000335c688>:0x00000003d0b238>
```

This is line #1:

```
 <%= form_for(@playlist) do |f| %>
```

This is what I get for `rake routes` if that helps at all:

```
            Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                  Controller#Action
    user_playlists GET    /users/:user_id/playlists(.:format)          playlists#index
                   POST   /users/:user_id/playlists(.:format)          playlists#create
 new_user_playlist GET    /users/:user_id/playlists/new(.:format)      playlists#new
edit_user_playlist GET    /users/:user_id/playlists/:id/edit(.:format) playlists#edit
     user_playlist GET    /users/:user_id/playlists/:id(.:format)      playlists#show
                   PATCH  /users/:user_id/playlists/:id(.:format)      playlists#update
                   PUT    /users/:user_id/playlists/:id(.:format)      playlists#update
                   DELETE /users/:user_id/playlists/:id(.:format)      playlists#destroy
             users GET    /users(.:format)                             users#index
                   POST   /users(.:format)                             users#create
          new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                         users#new
         edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                    users#edit
              user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                         users#show
                   PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                         users#update
                   PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                         users#update
                   DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                         users#destroy
              root GET    /                                            default_pages#home
            signup GET    /signup(.:format)                            users#new
            signin GET    /signin(.:format)                            users#signin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors:

```
undefined method `playlists_path' for #<#<Class:0x0000000335c688>
```

and

`user_playlist GET    /users/:user_id/playlists/:id(.:format)`

Gives a clear reason of the error you have.

```
<%= form_for(@playlist) do|f| %>
```

should be

```
<%= form_for([@user, @playlist]) do|f| %>
```

Or `current_user`, what is important is you need to pass the `user` object.

**Explanation :**

If you have noticed in a `update` action (taking that you redirect to a show  page after you update) instead of `redirect_to user_path(@user)` we can do just `redirect_to @user`, from which Rails infers that you are redirecting to the show path of user.

It is a similar situation here, similarly if you are having a `form_for` for the playlist and you pass only `@playlist` instead of `[@user, @playlist]` then it woud try to find `new_playlist_path`, which isn't in your route and will show an error.

This is a short [gist](https://gist.github.com/aghosh47/84268cbf2f18b529b178) on how you might do it.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. I tried replacing @playlist with [@user, @playlist] and I'm getting the same error. What else could it be?

Comment: changing it from @playlist to "[:user, @playlist] " worked. But now when I submit the new playlist, it complains about more playlist routing. There's a lot of places with "@playlist"...isn't there some way to generate correct paths so that I don't have to go fix all of these erroneous paths?

Comment: Do you have @user available in your playlist_controller.rb 's new? update the code or gist your codes at gist.github.com , the less you show us, the less we can help :)

Comment: to your second problem, if you have emacs then you can go to the project folder and say Alt+x grep Enter grep -nH -ri \@playlist Enter . that would show you all the place and you can click on the paths go and edit. it will be a little easier. Else maybe your can find some regex to do that for you .

Comment: Here's all the relevant portions of the code: https://gist.github.com/izikperz/9d2c7077a274ac0ffffc.

Would really appreciate your input. Thanks

Comment: ah, you don't have @user in your controller, if you don't have the object available in the relevant action then you can't have it in your view. Are you using devise?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64244/discussion-between-user2804881-and-argentum47).

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
<%= form_for(@playlist) do |f| %>
```

Should be This:

```
<%= form_for [@user, @playlist] do |f| %>
```

note the square brackets